# Why does this JSON fail only in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, json

I'm using the JSON framework from http://code.google.com/p/json-framework. The JSON below fails with this error:

```
-JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=5 UserInfo=0x124a20 "Unescaped control character '0xd'",
Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 UserInfo=0x11bc20 "Object value expected for key: Phone",
Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 UserInfo=0x1ac6e0 "Expected value while parsing array"
```

)

JSON being parsed:

```
[
    {
    "id" :"2422",
    "name" :"BusinessA",
    "address" :"7100 U.S. 50",
    "lat" :"38.342945",
    "lng" :"-90.390701",
    "CityId" :"11",
    "StateId" :"38",
    "CategoryId" :"1",
    "Phone" :"(200) 200-2000",
    "zip" :"00010"
    }
]
```

I think 0xd represents a carriage.  When I put the above JSON in TextWrangler, I don't see any carriage returns.  I got the JSON by doing "po myjson" in the debugger.  It passes this validator: http://json.parser.online.fr/.  Can anyone see what the problem may be?

Comment: What does `od -c` have to say about the output?

Comment: well something to do with the value for key "Phone" ...

Comment: Where are you guys getting this info from?

Comment: If I escape all quotes in the string with a backslash and send that value into the JSON parser, it works fine.  I printed out both values in the debugger and checked them in TextWranger.  They are exactly the same.  Yet - the one coming over the web doesn't parse.

Comment: I discovered in the JSON framework method fragmentWithString, there was an extra \r.  I removed it and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may well be getting bad data from the web service, or in an unexpected encoding.  Using `po myjson` (or `NSLog()`) and then copy-pasting is going to omit any non-printable characters, so even if you do have a stray 0xd, the web-based validator isn't going to see it.

You should try something like `[myjson rangeOfString:@"\15"]` to check for the 0xd (octal 15 being equivalent to hex 0xd).